# Resistance in closed Circle

Tags: electrical-resistance

A wire of resistance $10 \Omega$ is bent in form of closed cirle. How do I find resistance across its diameter.

Please don't consider this problem as homework question, just provide some hints, and make the problem clear, i.e. if we had to bent wire and made diameter also with this wire or only circle not diameter with this wire. What is actual meaning of **across diameter**, please make it clear by providing even rough diagram, please, it would be great help.

Comment: Can you provide a full sketch of the circuit you are proposing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the wire is a circle and you measure across its diameter, you are basically creating two possible paths for the current: clockwise or anti clockwise, for half the circumference.

[image]

Once you can see how this is a parallel circuit you will be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: the same applies for any 2 distinct points(not necessarily diametrically opposite.

Comment: please give numerical answer, is it 2.5?

Comment: I see two parallel resistors of five ohms. We are not supposed to give "answers" to "homework like" questions which this most definitely is.

Comment: ok, we will not violate regulations, between your figure really helped me.